# denormalize csv file with python / pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file structured as:

```
Location Parameter

A            10
A            20
B            14
B            16
C            15
C             9
C             6
```

I can easily get this in to a dataframe with read_csv.

I would like to use python / pandas to convert the dataframe to get columns for each of the A, B, C, and populate the values by the corresponding parameter, e.g.

```
A    B     C
10   14   15
20   16    9
NA   NA    6
```

with the ultimate goal of doing a boxplot on the dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't hit on the right pivoting/stacking approach -- someone else will probably come up with the right way -- so I fell back on `groupby`:

```
>>> df
  Location  Parameter
0        A         10
1        A         20
2        B         14
3        B         16
4        C         15
5        C          9
6        C          6
>>> cd = {k: v.reset_index(drop=True) for k,v in df.groupby("Location")["Parameter"]}
>>> pd.DataFrame(cd)
    A   B   C
0  10  14  15
1  20  16   9
2 NaN NaN   6
```

Comment: strange, I thought this fits very well with the `pivot` example in [the doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html), but I keep on getting `AssertionError('Length of index, columns, and values must be the same')`.

Answer (score 0):

To make a box-plot, the result of the groupby would suffice:

```
grouped = data.groupby('Location')
grouped.boxplot(subplots=False)
```

Comment: Did this actually produce the right result?  For me it gives a seven-row dataframe, not three.